# Finding the position of a succession of blanks in large data set - EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm going through a large amount meteorological data through excel in order to do some climatic modelling on a building. As a lot of data out there, there are some missing chunks.

So my first concern was to figure out the largest succession of blanks in my data I have done this by using `=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(T5:T101893="",ROW(T5:T101893)),IF(T5:T101893<>"",ROW(T5:T101893))))`.

So this returns the maximum succession of blanks in a given column. In my case the maximum succession of blank cells was 28.

**What I would like to figure out is where in the 101,893 lines is that succession of 28 blanks.**

I've tried scouring the internet without much success. I've also tried using the `match` and `index` functions by trying to match an array of 28 blanks (which obviously didn't work) or an array of 28 `1`s (I made an extra column next to my data with `=if(T5="",1,0))`, so it could match my array to the one in that column and return its position. It returned an incorrect position.

Comment: Instead of hitting my head on wall in getting the results using built-in worksheet functions I simply write UDF which takes care of all my requirement as wanted in lesser time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following simplified example below, the helper column tracks the 'run' of blanks using:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(A2)),B1+1,1)
```

Which you copy down to the last row of data. You can then use this formula to get the row of the max of the 'longest' run:

```
=MATCH(MAX(B2:B25),B2:B25)+1
```

In that formula, I've use `+1` (at the end) because there is 1 row with headers. In your sheet it needs to be `+x` where `x` is the number of headers and blank rows etc at the top of your sheet.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Robin, this seems like a good general solution to my problem :). However the match max function isn't returning the correct line... I'm going to try at it a bit more and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Olivier. In the MATCH and MAX function I use `+1` because there is 1 row with headers. In your sheet it needs to be `+x` where X is the number of headers and blank rows etc at the top of your sheet. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Robin it returns the correct line number now :).

Answer (score -1):

Conditional Formatting might help, once you know how many sequential blanks to look for. Select entire data area (assumed starting in A1), clear any existing CF from it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A28,"")=28
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Unless you have other red fill in the sheet, should be very evident where such a sequence starts, column by column. If in doubt, filter each column in turn for blanks.

If your sheet then grinds to a halt, apply standard red fill where the CF has and then remove CF from the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but with conditional formatting I would have to go through the data to see where the blanks occur, and I'd prefer for it to be quicker.

Comment: I agree with you. I read your solution more closely and it wouldn't be time consuming. I just don't understand how the countif would work. if you put a countif(A1:A28) for example, it counts the number of blanks in the column and would return exactly that, in my case in returns 596 which does not = 28 so the statement is always false. And the conditional formatting does not work.